# Generate, store and clean data across multiple process

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, gunicorn, horizontal-scaling

I have a simple application which stores it's runtime data at say `/tmp` of host machine. This data is used by different workers of same application.

When ever I start my app I want to make sure no data from previous session is stored there so I have to clean up that data.

But when I am deploying this on kubernetes if a pod is killed and re-starts the data is cleared. How can we avoid this.

```
# Sample of how things are getting done
class Work:
    def __init__(self):
        # Code Remove everything inside /tmp directory

    def work(self):
        # Generate userdata in /tmp directory
```

This app is hosted by `flask` using `gunicorn`. This works perfectly when we run it in simple environment.

But when we run it on `kubernetes` if pod gets killed new pod is created and this will remove existing data from `/tmp` directory. Which resets the information we've collected till now.

This looks like a general problem people must have encountered in time. Please suggest me some existing methodology for this.

Comment: Can you keep the data anywhere other than the local filesystem, for example, in a database?  The container filesystem is inherently temporary and you will lose data if it's only stored there; sharing files between containers is hard, especially in Kubernetes, and can lead to various more or less subtle problems.

Answer (score -1):

If you are storing it on the Host machine, which means mounting the file system using the `HostPath` then even if POD is restarting data should be there.

You might be writing files or data to the POD file system so if POD restart it will be empty if i understood it clearly.

In this case, you can use the HostPath which will mount the POD file system to Node's(Host) machine. Also, keep the POD name as a prefix

so your file system will be `/tmp/<POD Name>/data-here`

To get the POD name you can use the **Downward API**, i think with this case there won't be any changes required on the APP side minor changes are required in YAML only.

Below an example, you can notice the `subPathExpr: $(pod_name)` and Env to get the POD name.

Data will be written at `/var/log/app-data/<POD-Name>/`

**Example**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "3"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: app
  name: app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: app
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/component: app
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: pod_name
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        image: <IMAGE>
        name: app
        ports:
        - containerPort: 443
          name: app-tomcat-port
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /tmp
          name: app-data
          subPathExpr: $(pod_name)
      volumes:
      - hostPath:
          path: /var/log/app_data
          type: DirectoryOrCreate
        name: app-data
```

Read more about the **hostpath** : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath

Subpath expression doc : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath-expanded-environment

**Update**

As David corrected, with the above solution you might need to use the **Node selector** or **Affinity** to schedule POD on the specific node and it will work however it's not a scalable solution.

Assigning Pods to Nodes : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/

As your PODs need to run on a **single Node** then it will get older files if scheduled to another node it won't get files with **HostPath** method.

If you want to run it on multiple Nodes you have to implement a shared **filesystem** or **NFS**

**MinIO** : https://min.io/

Comment: A `hostPath` volume isn't the right answer here: if a pod is deleted and rescheduled on a different node, the data won't follow it.

Comment: Yes, David, you are right, i just thought he might be facing an issue when POD restart but if POD is deleted and rescheduled to another it would be hard to manage will update the answer. Thankyou for pointing out and correcting me.